# Creating a grid with numbered spaces and other markings

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

I am writing a graph theory paper about forbidden induced subgraphs. My coauthors and I have a list of 167 graphs that we would like to include in a diagram in the paper. I have generated all of these graphs in Mathematica.

I am trying use Mathematica to make the diagram. I would like to put the graphs into a grid (which I have already done using the Grid function). I have a frame around each section of the grid. I would like this grid to be numbered, so that each section has a small number in the corner of the frame. I would also like to label the graphs within each frame with various characters, corresponding to various properties they have. For example, I may want certain graphs toi have an asterisk next to them.

My question is this: is Grid the right way to do this? I don't know a lot of commands and I can't find the answer elsewhere. Grid doesn't seem to be able to put numbers into the corners of the frames.

I can provide more detail if necessary.

---

I like Sascha's answer about putting the text into a row below below each row of graphs. However I now have the following conundrum: I want to make the rows containing the graphs uniform in size, and I also want the rows containing text to be uniform, but much smaller. How do I control the size of the rows separately?

Comment: You can use `Epilog` in `Graph[]` along with `Text[]` and/or `Inset[]`.

Comment: `Grid` is exactly what you want to use. It takes some tuning but generally is very adaptable. You could for instance put your numbering and text into rows above or beneath a row of individual graphs.

Comment: Hi Dave, consider registering so that you don't easily lose the ability to edit your question for clarifications or additions.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy will be to make a `Column` that consists of the number at the right with the image below.

First I make some fake image data (this will not be of interest to you).

```
images = Map[ExampleData[#] &, ExampleData["TestImage"][[1 ;; 8]]];

images = Map[Function[img, ImageTransformation[img, # &, 64]], images];
```

Now using the list of eight images a new list dimensioned four by two is created that has a number in the upper right hand corner.

```
numberedImages =  Partition[
  Map[Column[{#, images[[#]]}, Alignment -> Right] &, Range[8]], 2]
```

Then execute `Grid` on the result:

```
Grid@numberedImages
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may very well want to `Style` the numbers to display smaller numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Labeled` and `Overlay` as follows (using @Jack's example):

```
img = ImageResize[#, {100, 100}] & /@ ExampleData /@ ExampleData["TestImage"][[;; 8]];

img2 = MapAt[Overlay[{#, Style["*", 40, Red]}, Alignment -> Right] &, 
   img, {{1}, {3}, {5}, {6}, {8}}];
Grid[Partition[MapIndexed[Labeled[#, Style[First@#2, 16], {{Top, Right}}] &, img2], 4], 
    Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, use `Panel` instead of `Labeled`:

```
Panel@Grid[Partition[MapIndexed[Panel[#, Style[First@#2, 16], {{Top, Right}}] &, img2], 4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]